# Loading entries from a list made from .csv file

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve data from a series of lists that have been populated from a single .csv file

i have the entire list added to a Dictionary and abbreviations from "lol" speak

so far i have it able to search through the list/dictionary and determine whether the item that is searched for is present or not. All i want to do it to write the:

```
                     abbreviation - full meaning
```

into the console

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace expanded_meanings
{  

    class Program
    {

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
Dictionary<string, string> lolspeak_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"H:\twitter.csv"));
        List<string> short_name = new List<string>();
        List<string> longer_name = new List<string>();

int count=0;
string search  = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {

            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            lolspeak.Add(values[0], values[1]);
            short_name.Add(values[0]);
            longer_name.Add(values[1]);
            count = count + 1;
        }    

if (short_name.Contains(search))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item found");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
        Console.ReadLine();

}
            //if (short_name = user_search);                       
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `short_name` and `long_name` lists.  So, instead of `if(short_name.Contains(search))` you could just use your dictionary `if(lolspeak.ContainsKey(search))`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need the `short_name` and `long_name` as those values are contained within the `lolspeak_dictionary`,  You can access them by using the `Keys` and `Values` properties of a `Dictionary`.

As for searching for the `abbreviation - full meaning` you can simply use your current code as

```
if (lolspeak_dictionary.ContainsKey(search))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", search, lolspeak_dictionary[search]);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' - Not Found", search);    
}
```

**UPDATE**:

The method call [Console.WriteLine("'{0}' - Not Found", search);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx)    works by using substitution.  The value of `search`, is placed in the spot of `{0}`.  The means that `{0} - Not Found` if search is `WOTR` you will get `WOTR - Not found`.

In the case of `Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", search, lolspeak_dictionary[search]);`.  If `search` is `WOTA`, you would get `WOTA - Will of the Ancients`.

Additional Resources

- [Dictionary MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Keys MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Values MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Understanding Dictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/673624/Understanding-Dictionaries-in-NET)

Comment: sorry but i was under the impresssion that anything between "" will be written onto whatever the handler is?

Comment: What I used about is apart of the `Console.Writeline(string, object, ..)` series.  You can see more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx).  Basically `{0} - {1}` is like algebra substitution.  The values of `search` and `lolspeak_dictionary[search]` are added placed into the spot of `{0}` and `{1}` respectively.